# Bash script to run multiple commands in one block " or sub command"

Tags: bash

I need to make bash script that run multiple commands under specific variable ie, if I type in bash `appserver` (for example) it runs all the below commands 
but I need to put them in block :

```
appserver
[
read -e -p "please enter weblogic username: " user
read -e -s -p "please enter weblogic password: " pass
echo ""
echo 'JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.management.username='$user' -Dweblogic.management.password='$pass'"; export JAVA_OPTIONS' > /home/oracle/ofm_start.sh
echo "# Start NodeManager"  >> /home/oracle/ofm_start.sh
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the commands in a file with a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -e -p "please enter weblogic username: " user
read -e -s -p "please enter weblogic password: " pass
echo ""
echo "JAVA_OPTIONS=\"-Dweblogic.management.username='$user' -Dweblogic.management.password='$pass'\"; export JAVA_OPTIONS" > /home/oracle/ofm_start.sh
echo "# Start NodeManager"  >> /home/oracle/ofm_start.sh
```

Note that I corrected the quoting in your `echo` line since your original version didn't keep the single quotes.

Then, make the script executable with `chmod +x foo.sh` and run it with `./foo.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` has [functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html) like many other programming languages.

```
function appserver
{
    read -e -p "please enter weblogic username: " user
    read -e -s -p "please enter weblogic password: " pass
    echo ""
    echo 'JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.management.username='$user' -Dweblogic.management.password='$pass'"; export JAVA_OPTIONS' > /home/oracle/ofm_start.sh
    echo "# Start NodeManager"  >> /home/oracle/ofm_start.sh
}
```